# Pubnub's rtc-controller.js compatible with webrtc v2 and pubnub v4

Tags: pubnub

I couldn't find  rtc-controller.js compatible with webrtc-v2 and pubnub-v4!
Currently it works fine with pubnub-v3 and webrtc-v1.

Problem is that `mystream` is not get initialled properly.

Comment: Yes, the v2 which you are referring to here: https://github.com/stephenlb/webrtc-sdk uses the PubNub REST API and circumvents the PubNub v4 SDK. PubNub is releasing a ChatEngine WebRTC plugin soon, so if you are using WebRTC for Chat with JavaScript, you're in luck.

Comment: I am stack with webrtc-v2.js trying to create a one-to-many style broadcasting. call examples (ie. tutorials/multicall.html) is based on assumption that all parties have the camera is on.